# Drawing attached figure

Tags: diagrams

May I ask how I could draw attached figure with LaTex?

Sincerely
Ehsan[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may ask, but as it stands this is a do-it-for-me question. Please add your attempts here (as minimal compilable code example) and clarify at which specific point you need help.

Comment: See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Dear,
Your are right. I have to prepare a minimal code and after somehow attempts ask question. However I really didn't work much with Latex and it is almost impossible for me to do that, especially graphic codes. BTW I apologize for asking help in this way.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty mess but maybe someone can clean it up a little bit. (E.g. declare the used node style as a „real“ node style [`\node[NAME] …`] and so on.)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 45,every node/.style={font=\LARGE}]
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (7,9);
        \node[fill=white,inner xsep=.6cm,inner ysep=.3cm] (a) at (0,6.5) {};
            \draw (a.north west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.north east);
            \draw (a.south west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.south east);
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
            \node[fill=white,inner xsep=.6cm,inner ysep=.3cm] (a) at (0,7.5) {};
                \draw (a.north west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.north east);
                \draw (a.south west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.south east);
        \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,yshift=-5cm]
                \node[fill=white,inner xsep=.6cm,inner ysep=.3cm] (a) at (0,7.5) {};
                    \draw (a.north west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.north east);
                    \draw (a.south west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.south east);
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
                \node[fill=white,inner xsep=.6cm,inner ysep=.3cm] (a) at (0,6.5) {};
                    \draw (a.north west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.north east);
                    \draw (a.south west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.south east);
            \end{scope}
            \node[left] at (0,9) {$T$};
                \draw[->] (0,9.5) --+ (0,1) node[below left,xshift=-5,yshift=3] {$t$};
            \node at (3.5,4.5) {$\Omega\times I$};
            \node[below=5] at (3.5,0) {$\Omega\times 0$};
            \node[above=5] at (3.5,9) {$\Omega\times T$};
                \node[left=5] at (0,0) {0};
            \draw[->] (7.5,0) --+ (1,0) node[below right,yshift=-3,xshift=-3] {$x$};
                \draw (0,7.5) -- (9,9) node[above=10] {$\partial\,\Omega\times I$} -- (7,7.5);
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \begin{scope}[shift={(15,0)}]
                    \draw (0,0) rectangle (7,9);
                        \node[fill=white,inner xsep=.6cm,inner ysep=.3cm] (a) at (0,6.5) {};
                            \draw (a.north west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.north east);
                            \draw (a.south west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.south east);
                    \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
                        \node[fill=white,inner xsep=.6cm,inner ysep=.3cm] (a) at (0,7.5) {};
                            \draw (a.north west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.north east);
                            \draw (a.south west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.south east);
                    \end{scope}
                    \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,yshift=-5cm]
                        \node[fill=white,inner xsep=.6cm,inner ysep=.3cm] (a) at (0,7.5) {};
                            \draw (a.north west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.north east);
                            \draw (a.south west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.south east);
                    \end{scope}
                    \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
                        \node[fill=white,inner xsep=.6cm,inner ysep=.3cm] (a) at (0,6.5) {};
                            \draw (a.north west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.north east);
                            \draw (a.south west) to[bend left=40] ($(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) to[bend right=40] (a.south east);
                    \end{scope}
                \draw (0,5.5) -- (7,5.5);
                \draw (0,4.5) -- (7,4.5);
                \draw (0,3.5) -- (7,3.5);
                    \draw[xshift=-.5cm] (7/3,5.5) --+ (0,-2);
                    \draw[xshift=.5cm] (14/3,5.5) --+ (0,-2);
                    \draw (3.5,5.5) --+ (0,-2);
                \draw (0,8) -- (7,8);
                    \begin{scope}[yshift=3.5cm]
                        \draw[xshift=-.5cm] (7/3,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                        \draw[xshift=.5cm] (14/3,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                        \draw (3.5,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                    \end{scope}
                \draw (0,1) -- (7,1);
                    \begin{scope}[yshift=-4.5cm]
                        \draw[xshift=-.5cm] (7/3,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                        \draw[xshift=.5cm] (14/3,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                        \draw (3.5,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                    \end{scope}
                \draw[->] (0,9.5) --+ (0,1) node[below left,xshift=-5,yshift=3] {$t$};
                \draw[->] (7.5,0) --+ (1,0) node[below right,yshift=-3,xshift=-3] {$x$};
                    \node[left=30] at (0,0) {$t_0$};
                    \node[left=30] at (0,1) {$t_1$};
                        \node[left=30] at (0,3.5) {$t_n$};
                        \node[left=30] at (0,4.5) {$t_{n+1}$};
                        \node[left=30] at (0,5.5) {$t_{n+2}$};
                            \node[left=30] at (0,8) {$t_{N-1}$};
                            \node[left=30] at (0,9) {$t_N = T$};
            \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A slightly shorter version can be obtained by using `pic`s:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  broken line/.style={
    code={
      \fill [white] (-1,-0.25) rectangle (1,0.25);
      \draw (-0.5,-0.25) to[bend left=40] (0,-0.25) to[bend right=40] (0.5,-0.25);
      \draw (-0.5,0.25) to[bend left=40] (0,0.25) to[bend right=40] (0.5,0.25);
    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 45,every node/.style={font=\LARGE}]
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (7,9);
        \foreach \Coord in {(0,6.5),(0,2.5),(7,6.5),(7,2.5)}
        {\path \Coord pic{broken line};}
            \node[left] at (0,9) {$T$};
            \draw[->] (0,9.5) --+ (0,1) node[below left,xshift=-5,yshift=3] {$t$};
            \node at (3.5,4.5) {$\Omega\times I$};
            \node[below=5] at (3.5,0) {$\Omega\times 0$};
            \node[above=5] at (3.5,9) {$\Omega\times T$};
            \node[left=5] at (0,0) {0};
            \draw[->] (7.5,0) --+ (1,0) node[below right,yshift=-3,xshift=-3] {$x$};
            \draw (0,7.5) -- (9,9) node[above=10] {$\partial\,\Omega\times I$} -- (7,7.5);
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \begin{scope}[shift={(15,0)}]
                    \draw (0,0) rectangle (7,9);
        \foreach \Coord in {(0,6.5),(0,2.5),(7,6.5),(7,2.5)}
        {\path \Coord pic{broken line};}
                \draw (0,5.5) -- (7,5.5);
                \draw (0,4.5) -- (7,4.5);
                \draw (0,3.5) -- (7,3.5);
                    \draw[xshift=-.5cm] (7/3,5.5) --+ (0,-2);
                    \draw[xshift=.5cm] (14/3,5.5) --+ (0,-2);
                    \draw (3.5,5.5) --+ (0,-2);
                \draw (0,8) -- (7,8);
                    \begin{scope}[yshift=3.5cm]
                        \draw[xshift=-.5cm] (7/3,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                        \draw[xshift=.5cm] (14/3,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                        \draw (3.5,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                    \end{scope}
                \draw (0,1) -- (7,1);
                    \begin{scope}[yshift=-4.5cm]
                        \draw[xshift=-.5cm] (7/3,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                        \draw[xshift=.5cm] (14/3,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                        \draw (3.5,5.5) --+ (0,-1);
                    \end{scope}
                \draw[->] (0,9.5) --+ (0,1) node[below left,xshift=-5,yshift=3] {$t$};
                \draw[->] (7.5,0) --+ (1,0) node[below right,yshift=-3,xshift=-3] {$x$};
                    \node[left=30] at (0,0) {$t_0$};
                    \node[left=30] at (0,1) {$t_1$};
                        \node[left=30] at (0,3.5) {$t_n$};
                        \node[left=30] at (0,4.5) {$t_{n+1}$};
                        \node[left=30] at (0,5.5) {$t_{n+2}$};
                            \node[left=30] at (0,8) {$t_{N-1}$};
                            \node[left=30] at (0,9) {$t_N = T$};
            \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to simplify your nice code a bit. Of course, if you don't like it I'll be happy to revert the changes. BTW, Alan Munn, who is always right (unless he disagrees with cfr), [suggest so add a picture](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7758/121799). So after I added a screen shot I also upvoted your nice answer. ;-)

Comment: @marmot: This was exactly that what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @Ehsan_Taghizadeh: Yeah, just mark the answer as the best one …